# Apple Watch iOS 3 control center does not show unlock symbol any longer

Tags: apple-watch, control-center

Some days ago I mentioned by accident that my Apple Watch control center (the menu which appears when you swipe from bottom to top) does no longer show the symbol to lock the watch. My wifes Apple Watch still contains this lock button, so I'm wondering what I need to do to let it reappear. Any ideas?

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you get the os version 3.1.1?

It seems that with 3.1.1 the "problem" is considered a "feature", i.e. was intentionally removed (see http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/12/14/watchos-3-1-1-disables-lock-feature-in-control-center-here-are-four-workarounds/ )

The article also lists various workarounds, the best seems to be disabling wrist detection (Settings → General → Wrist Detection)

The others are

1. Use Water-Lock instead
2. Lock your watch via Workout app

Comment: That appears to be right (I wonder why I didn't find that article).